# Nginx Rewrite rule to replace '?' with %3f

Tags: nginx

Nginx is serving only static files, yet, some of file names contains '?'. Yes, the question mark.

All URLs that contains '?' yield 404 even though file actually exists. e.g.

```
> GET /foo?lang=ar.html HTTP/1.1
...
...
< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
```

While a file named **foo?lang=ar.html** does exists in the expected location.

```
> GET /foo%3flang=ar.html HTTP/1.1
...
...
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

How do I write a rewrite directive so all '?' will be redirected to %3f?

Answer (score 1):

You should [**url-encode**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_encoding) your query string to escape special characters such as `?` and `=`

Specifically, the name of your file you have to request for, once encoded, is this:

```
foo%3Flang%3Dar.html
```

In Javascript you can url-encode the filename with `encodeURIComponent()` function, in PHP you have `urlencode()`.

Comment: Yep, the question is how to config nginx to redirect/rewrite the request that way (question rephrased to be more clear about this)

Answer (score 1):

You MUST encode the `?` as `%3F` before the http call to nginx.

The reason is that the [url rfc](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1738.html) reserves the `?` character as a special character (specifcally see section 3.3). Consequently nginx will, correctly, interpret an unescaped `?` character as the end of the path part of the url